# Unable to Use pytest-mock in pytest to Verify Construction and Instance Method Calls Simultaneously

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

To start, I'm using the pytest-mock and pytest packages to test a software project that I'm working on.

I have a situation where I'm testing a class in a module and trying to mock out a composite object that it instantiates from its `__init__` method. When I do this, I am able to assert that the `__init__` method is properly called, but when I try to assert that an instance method is called, I get an assertion error.

When I debug pytest by passing the `--pdb` option to it, I verify by checking the `MagicMock()` object's `.method.called` property that it "wasn't" called, but then when I check the `MagicMock()` object's `.method_calls` property, I see that it was in fact called.

Here's a simple example to show what I mean:

#### test.py

```
import module

def test_Calling(mocker):
    mocker.patch('module.Called', autospec=True)

    module.Calling('argument')

    module.Called.assert_called_once_with('argument')
    module.Called.check_me.assert_called_once()
```

#### module.py

```
class Calling(object):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        called_instance = Called(argument)
        called_instance.check_me()

class Called(object):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        pass

    def check_me(self):
        pass
```

And here's the pytest/pdb session:

```
(venv) C:\pytest-issue>pytest --pdb test.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.6, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: C:\pytest-issue, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.5.0
collected 1 items

test.py F
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> traceback >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

mocker = <pytest_mock.MockFixture object at 0x000000000431B2E8>

    def test_Calling(mocker):
        mocker.patch('module.Called', autospec=True)

        module.Calling('argument')

        module.Called.assert_called_once_with('argument')
>       module.Called.check_me.assert_called_once()

test.py:9:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

_mock_self = <MagicMock name='Called.check_me' spec='instancemethod' id='70367608'>

    def assert_called_once(_mock_self):
        """assert that the mock was called only once.
        """
        self = _mock_self
        if not self.call_count == 1:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times." %
                   (self._mock_name or 'mock', self.call_count))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'check_me' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

venv\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py:915: AssertionError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> c:\pytest-issue\venv\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py(915)assert_called_once()
-> raise AssertionError(msg)
(Pdb) up
> c:\pytest-issue\test.py(9)test_Calling()
-> module.Called.check_me.assert_called_once()
(Pdb) module.Called.method_calls
[call().check_me()]
(Pdb) module.Called.check_me.called
False
```

For the life of me, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In this circumstance, do I need to assert `.Called.method_calls`? If so, that looks like I would have to put a lot of logic into my tests, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it turned out that I was quite ignorant in how you test a patched module.

```
import module

def test_Calling(mocker):
    mock_Called = mocker.patch('module.Called')

    module.Calling('argument')

    mock_called.assert_has_calls([
        mocker.call('argument'),
        mocker.call().check_me()])
```

The important things to consider here are that you need to store the return value of mocker.patch, as that will give a reference to the `MagicMock` object that gets instantiated and patched in over `module.Called`. Next, when you wish to test that an instance method is being called, you should use the `assert_has_calls` method on the `MagicMock` instance, passing it `call()` arguments that reflect what is being called. `call()` by itself refers to the `__new__/__init__` calls, and `call().method` refers to a call made against an instance method.

Since figuring this out, I've been able to use the `pytest-mock` module quite successfully.